# Calculating a constant movement rate between 2D vectors

Tags: java, c#, vector, libgdx

In a 2D game I need to move a character between 2 points on the screen. I did this in another project with 3D vectors in C# but am unsure how to do the same with 2D and in java.

Tried this in java but it does not pass as valid syntax:

```
Vector2 step = pos.add(moveTarget.sub(pos)).clamp(0,1) * speed * delta;
```

3D calculation in C#:

```
Vector3 newPos = transform.position + (targetPos - transform.position).normalized * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding the positions together, in LibGDX both Vector2 and Vector3 have a lerp() function here is the documentation.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#lerp-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-float-

You should be able to do something like this to achieve the desired results:

```
Vector2 start = new Vector2(0, 0);
Vector2 end = new Vector2(100, 100);

public void render(float delta) {
    start.lerp(end, delta);
}
```

Additionally LibGDX has an Interpolation class which you can statically use methods from to achieve more complex interpolations past just the basic lerp() function.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: The problem with interpolation is that the speed is not consistent. Moving different distances will result in different movement speeds which I do not want. I figured out the calculation now.